# nhibernate upgrade 2.1 to 3.3, exception when using DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer

Tags: nhibernate

We've upgraded NHibernate from 2.xx to 3.3. It works well but we have some usages of

```
SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
```

And now we get "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception when doing

```
.List<Entity>()
```

The Stack trace shows that the error comes from 

       `at NHibernate.Type.TypeHelper.Disassemble(Object[] row, ICacheAssembler[] types, Boolean[] nonCacheable, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
   at NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache.Put(QueryKey key, ICacheAssembler[] returnTypes, IList result, Boolean isNaturalKeyLookup, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.PutResultInQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IType[] resultTypes, IQueryCache queryCache, QueryKey key, IList result)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListUsingQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results)`

Any clues?

I found this: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2961

And if you remove, fetchmode.join or distinctrootentitytransformer or cache, it works.